# Warning-session start errors and cannot login to administer

Tags: login

I am trying to log into my webpage to do administration and all I get is "Warning - session start errors" and I can't log in to disable the problem.

Answer (score 0):

its not clear what the problem is, question is not explained well, but looks like you are trying to disable plugin that is causing problems,

first you need to analyze which plugin is creating problem then

you can goto the WP-CONTENT/PLUGINS/ Directory through FTP

and Rename the plugin folder name so it would be automatically deactivated.

might be this will help you.

thanks,